# Google Chrome Add Bookmark Image

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, web

Recently Google has added a new interface when users click the star icon in the address bar to add a website to their bookmarks.

The UI displays the page title as well as anything from the meta description element if present, but I was wondering if there's a way to set the image that's displayed, or whether this is just purely decorative on Chrome's part:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be some datas included in the head part of the pages.
You probably know that you can use meta tags to set some favicon, gps coordinates, and many other things.
Some new tags, the [Opengraph](http://ogp.me/) meta tags, are now used to define some informations to best describe the content of the website you're browsing. For example, on facebook, when you share a link, these opengraph datas are used to create a small block which summarize and show a picture of the linked website.

So, to be clear and to speak about code, just try with this line in your head section:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

Tried it while writing this post on a little static website I'm working on, seems to work prefect !

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like Google collect all images on the webpage et allow you to choose which one you want for your bookmark.